Creating a windows script using nssm
I have a python script that continuosuly runs and sends data via socket to a server. Now i want to create a service of that script exe that users donwload the script runs as a backgroung service without human intervention and automatically restarts when the system restarts.
I wanted to integrate it to my application but there are some auth issues and also the script had to be run manually again  i want it to be like users downloads it once and all other work is automated .
Any tip, solution or resource would be appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The script is working fine and i am able to create an exe of of it but i want to To achieve a seamless installation process where the users only need to download and run the executable then  This installer will automate the tasks which is running the exe as a background service.Still the nssm is a better option for it as it is making a service to run on my pc but what about others the same exe isnt working as a service for them ?

to create an exe from py program use Pyinstaller, whit -w flag to suppress the consol.
To start the program after rebooting you can create a batch file, that starts the .exe program, in the folder: C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup, to create file use that code:
from os import environ

open(f"c:\\Users\\{environ.get('USERNAME')}\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\Program-launcher.bat", 'w').write(f"start {__file__}")

There are more elegant ways, but I prefer this one because it doesn't require you to be an admin, it doesn't require additional libraries and it doesn't mess around with system variables and it's very concise.
I hope I have understood the request well.
